# How to Retrieve / Get CAB FileUnique Version Number From C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, windows-mobile

I have an application in windows mobile 6.after deploying the application,it will create a CAB file.
I Want to Upload this CAB file To Server using File Upload Control From Asp.Net Web Form..

While Uploading I want to check the CAB file is already Uploaded Before by checking its version number[Unique Generated by .NET while Deploying] rather than Just its name.

How to get this unique version from C# ???

Please help me on this.....

Thanks in Advance

Comment: are you talking about versioning of a file have you looked into getting / storing the HashCode of that file for example.. if not you could just check the existance of a file based on the file name with the if File.Exist... please clarify if my assumtions are wrong

Comment: Its not about file existence...may be the same CAB file with different name available on the System.So we have to check unique version or something of that uploaded file to compare with files in server uploaded before.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use an MD5 hash of the file itself?  That's going to give you a pretty good uniqueness.

```
public string GetFileHash(string fileName)
{
    using (var stream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open))
    {
        var md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        var hash = md5.ComputeHash(stream);

        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < hash.Length; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(hash[i].ToString("x2"));
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```